# Spectra of two different symmetrizations of the same matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix. There are two easy ways to tranform it into a symmetric matrix:

1. take $B:=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$
2. take $C:=\sqrt{AA^T}$

$B,C$ are both symmetric, hence they both have $n$ real eigenvalues. $C$ is non-negative definite and its eigenvalues are called the *singular values* of $A$.

In general is there a relation between the eigenvalues of $B$ and those of $C$ ? Do they have the same spectral radius?

For example if the matrix $A$ is symmetric itself, then one has simply $B=A$, $C^2=A^2$ hence the eigenvalues of $B$, $C$ coincide up to sign.

Comment: A slightly more general statement is that if $A$ satisfies $AA^T = A^TA$ (i.e. $A$ is "normal"), then the eigenvalues of $B$ are the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $C$ are the absolute values of the ieigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no nice relation between the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. No, they do not necessarily have the same spectral radius. For an example where they have distinct spectral radii, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.
$$

Comment: We have $\rho(B)=\|B\|_2\le\frac12(\|A\|_2+\|A^T\|_2)=\|A\|_2=\rho(C)$.

Comment: According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value, ordering the eigenvalues of $B$ and those of $C$ we have $\lambda_i(B)\leq\lambda_i(C)$ for every $i=1,\dots,n$